# ifort is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am compiling a code in Fortran using Visual Studio 2010 using Intel Visual Fortran and I continue to get this message. The installation was completed without errors, and i don't think I need additional packages or libraries.

Comment: Don't you have an icon for a modified command prompt with ifort in the PATH variable in your newly created directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a general Windows question. When a command is not recognized, you typically need to modify your PATH variable. Create a Windows batch file with a line such as

set path=c:\foo;%path%

where c:\foo is the directory of the ifort.exe executable.